# Dump clipboard to stdout in follow mode (for piping)?

Tags: bash, clipboard

I'm aware of `xsel` and `xclip`, ( also discussed in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-the-clipboard ), and use them often.

However, now I would like to have the <s>primary</s> clipboard dumped to stdout, but in "follow mode". Currently, if I try this:

```
$ xclip -o
Currently, if I try this:
$ xsel -o
Currently, if I try this:
$
```

... the commands exit immediately.

What I would like instead, is a behavior similar to `tail -f /var/log/syslog` - that is, "follow mode": `tail` blocks the terminal, and whenever a new line shows in the file, it dumps it to standard output.

I'd like something similar, but for whenever I make a new copy (i.e., press Ctrl-C, or Ctrl-Shift-C in terminal) - that is, whenever I change the <s>primary</s> clipboard contents.

Is there a command that will help me do that in `bash`?

Comment: I do similar for myself
Would you be happy with a 16 line python script?

Comment: Thanks @Tagwint - would be quite happy with that `:)`

Comment: Are you using desktop which supports appindicators by any chance ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's a python solution. I don't think it needs comments, it does exactly what requested, but let me know if my assumption is wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys 
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from   gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk 

def pcallBack(*args):
    print pclip.wait_for_text() 

if __name__ == '__main__':    
        import signal    
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)    
        pclip = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY)
        pclip.connect('owner-change',pcallBack)
        Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Awesome, @Tagwint, thanks so much for that! It's just that I needed the dump only when I make a copy (that is, press Ctrl-C), your script dumps every time I make a new text selection - but that is easily fixed by changing `Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY` into `Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD` (corrected my OP to reflect that). Thanks again - cheers!